# Spark Scala issue

Tags: scala

I am searching in an rdd textfile a word say "Scala":

```
myRdd.map(line => if (line.split(" ").contain("Scala")) {("Scala", 1)})
```

Works fine.

But:

```
val l = "Scala"
myRdd.map(line => if (line.split(" ").contain(l)) {(l, 1)})
```

Does not work, It freezes the program without error.

It seems to be because of a local variable but can't figure out why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala infinite loop when replacing concret value by parameter name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983586/scala-infinite-loop-when-replacing-concret-value-by-parameter-name)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jasper-M,

```
final val lang_i
```

worked just fine. But I am very surprised this is not better known at least from all searches I did.

I would like in fact to do something like the following (not sure of the syntax) which does not work:

```
final val langs = List("Java", "Scala", "Python")
wikiRdd.flatMap(wa => langs.map(lang => if(wa.split(" ").contain(lang)) {(lang, 1)} ))
```

But final does't seem to work for a list. I will look more closely at the link provided, but a direct answer would quite ease my pain.

Also sorry for my ignorance, but I am interested also in an "scala" answer in the fact that I don't see how we can refactor or write a code without passing variables in lambda expression. I am still learning... but I'm curious to see how this list example can be solved.

Many thanks,
Ez